# Matrices for action wrt basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, representation-theory, invariance

Consider the permutation representation where $G=S_3$ on $\mathbb{C^3}$ with the action:

$\pi(g)e_i=e_{g(i)}$

$W=\{ \lambda_i e_i ; \sum \lambda_i=0 \}$ is an invariant subsoace of vector space $V$

matrices for the action on $W$ wrt basis $v_1=e_1+we_2+w^2e_3$ and $v_2=we_1+e_2+w^2e_3$ of $W$ where $w$ is a primitive third root of unity are given for two group elements as follows:

$\pi((12))=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}$

$\pi((23))=\begin{bmatrix}
0&w\\w^2&0
\end{bmatrix}$

Can someone please guide me through how these are calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the matrix representation of the action for $\pi((12))$ for example, you just let $\pi((12))$ act on each of the basis vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. So you have
    $$\pi((12))v_1 = \pi((12))e_1 + w\pi((12))e_2 + w^2\pi((12))e_3 = e_2 + we_1 + w^2e_3 = v_2$$
and thus with respect to the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ the first column of your matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ indicating that it simply switches the two basis vectors. Consequently the second column will be $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ giving the matrix $$\pi((12)) = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$. I will leave the second computation (of the matrix $\pi((23))$) up to you.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was wondering if you could tell me why the matrix dimension reduces from 3 by 3 to 2 by 2. Is it because we are only considering two basis vectors?

Comment: Yes. You have a 2 dimensional subspace generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$, which are expressed in terms of the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ of the ambient 3 dimensional space

Answer (score 0):

$$
\pi((12))(e_1+we_2+w^2e_3) = we_1+e_2+w^2e_3
$$$$
\pi((12))(we_1+e_2+w^2e_3) = e_1+we_2+w^2e_3
$$

$$
\pi((23))(e_1+we_2+w^2e_3) = e_1+w^2e_2+we_3 = w^2(we_1+e_2+w^2e_3)
$$$$
\pi((23))(we_1+e_2+w^2e_3) = we_1+w^2e_2+e_3 = w(e_1+w^2e_2+we_3)
$$